# Finding explicit solution to 2D system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In my studies of dynamics, I came across this ODE system given by:

> $ \dot{x} = -A \frac{\pi}{k}\cos{(\pi y)}\sin{(kx)} $
>
> $ \dot{y} = A\sin{(\pi y)}\cos{(kx)} $

where A and k are two non zero constants. I am interested in finding the vertical trajectory connecting the two fixed points (0,0) and (0,1), so if I substitute x=0 I get the velocity for y as: $ \dot{y} = A\sin{(\pi y)} $ which solving for specifically meaning to get the y(t) with time dependency is impossible to me as the integral is complicated with a trigonometric logarithm and I am unable to find the (x(t),y(t)) of the solution explicitly. I need it for Melnikov's method of an analysis of a periodic perturbation of the system.

Comment: have you tried Wolfram Alpha? Maple 2015 can solve the system

Comment: I know I just wanted to know the technique to do so not just the final answer

Comment: but the solution containes the inverse Jacobi function.

Comment: Even if we are only interested in the vertical solution I mentioned?

Comment: solve the first equation for $y$ and plug this in the second equation and differentiate the first equation for $t$ and plug this in the second one

Comment: Thanks I think you misunderstood me I am only interested in x=0 so I first plug this in the y equation and i need to find y in terms of t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRST PART , solving in the general case, but restricted to $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ : 
$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{dx}{dt} = -A \frac{\pi}{k}\cos{(\pi y)}\sin{(kx)} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = A\sin{(\pi y)}\cos{(kx)} 
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad k\frac{\cos(kx)}{\sin(kx)}dx = -\pi \frac{\cos(\pi y)}{\sin(\pi y)}dy $$
$\int k\frac{\cos(kx)}{\sin(kx)}dx +\int \pi \frac{\cos(\pi y)}{\sin(\pi y)}dy = \ln|\sin(kx)| +\ln|\sin(\pi y)| =$constant.
$$\sin(kx)\sin(\pi y)=c$$
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{\sin(kx)} \right)$$

SECOND PART, solving in case $x=0$ :
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = A\sin{(\pi y)}$$
If the starting point is $(x=0\:,\: y=0) \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=0 \quad\to\quad y(t)=0$

More gerenal : If the starting point is $(x=0\:,\: y=n) \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=0 \quad\to\quad y(t)=n$

If the starting point is $(x=0\:,\: y\neq n \text{ and } y\neq 0)$ :

$At=\int \frac{dy}{\sin(\pi y)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\ln|\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2}y\right) |+$constant.

$$y=\frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(e^{\pi A(t-t_0)} \right) \quad\implies\quad y\neq 0$$

At $t=0 : \quad\to\quad y_0=\frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(e^{-\pi At_0} \right) \quad\to\quad e^{-\pi At_0}=\tan(\pi y_0)$

IN SHORT :

If the starting point at $t=0$ is exactly $(x=0\:,\:y=0)$ there is no motion.

If the starting point at $t=0$ is not exactly $(x=0\:,\:y=0)$ but $(x=0\:,\:y=y_0\neq 0)$ :
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\tan(\pi y_0) e^{\pi At} \right)$$

Note : On physical viewpoint, subject to the study of instability at $(t=0\:,\: x=0\:,\:y=0)$, the validity of the above equation might be extended to this point.